# Is there any reason to switch to Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Forms development?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I can't find any new features or improvements for Windows Forms in Visual Studio 2010. Am I missing something? I guess there are new features to C# and other parts of .NET in general. Any reason specifically to the GUI development portion?

Answer (score 6):

I thought PEX was being added. I think it's valuable: 
[Pex Tutorial](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/pexcodediggertutorial.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Although it's not specific to GUI development IntelliTrace is reason enough for me to go to 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915(VS.100).aspx

If you have in-house users that test alpha or beta level versions of your application IntelliTrace is a great way to get more detail about what was happening during failures/unexpected situations.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not any REAL must haves to require an upgrade, but lots of little things that may make your lives easier.

In .net 4.0 (thus used in VS 2010), the charting controls are built in, as opposed to having to install them manually.  Not a ture reason to upgrade, but will make it easier if you use the charting controls.  [ScottGu's Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx)

In addition, other benefits to VS 2010 (not specific to WinForms, but will be beneficial) are [Searching and Navigating improvements](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/21/searching-and-navigating-code-in-vs-2010-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx), [Code Intellisense Improvements](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/22/vs-2010-code-intellisense-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx), [Add Reference Improvements](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/29/add-reference-dialog-improvements-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)